# Form respuestas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

He hecho un formulario en Google pero necesito que en la hoja de cálculo de respuestas se vaya almacenando en una columna concreta la url de la respuesta individual del formulario conforme se envía, para poder consultarla posteriormente o enviar el enlace por correo.e.
No puedo usar complementos.

He intentado montar un script pero sólo consigo obtener la url para poder editar la respuesta y quiero que sólo se pueda consultar.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías editar la pregunta y colocar el código que te da problemas para que podamos ayudarte?

Comment: Hola user87707 podrías pasarme el script por favor. Yo deseo exactamente generarla columna con la URL para editar la respuesta. Gracias "He hecho un formulario en Google pero necesito que en la hoja de cálculo de respuestas se vaya almacenando en una columna concreta la url de la respuesta individual del formulario conforme se envía, para poder consultarla posteriormente ...
He intentado montar un script pero sólo consigo obtener la url para poder editar la respuesta y quiero que sólo se pueda consultar."

Comment: Hola, EditResponse(){
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  var form= FormApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
     var formResponse = formResponses[i];
      var urlEdit = formResponse.getEditResponseUrl();
  
   }

  sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(urlEdit);

Comment: @CristianLaureano: En mi [respuesta](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89566/88163) a "Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script", aunque está en inglés se incluyen imágenes de cada paso. Seguramente te será útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los formularios de Google no tienen una URL a una vista de sólo lectura de una respuesta en particular.

Al menos no se habla de ello en [Centro de Ayuda de Documentos de Google](https://suppot.google.com/docs?hl=es) ni en https://developers.google.com/apps-script.

Una forma de hacerlo es que por cada respuesta generes un archivo con la entradas de la respuesta, este lo compartas con cualquiera que tenga el enlace y registres dicho enlace en la hoja de respuestas de tu hoja de cálculo.